# Renewal price of “Domain & Hosting”

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, hosting, web-hosting

What if my website domain had a huge **traffic** and **high ranking**. is there are any chances for price increase over normal rates after 1 year , at **renewal** time ?. is there any hosting site provide **same rate** for "domain renew & hosting " as many years as we want to host?

Answer (score 1):

Traffic or ranking don't affect renewal prices **unless** you let the domain expire. If you do, you might have to pay a hefty fee, depending on the domain registrar or if another person registers the domain before you can renew.

Domain prices vary by domain extension, not every extension (.com, .net, .org, etc.) cost the same, and some registrars (domain.com, godaddy, etc.) even charge different prices for the same extension.

You can buy a domain for more than 1 year, and get it at different prices for different periods depending on the registrar and if it's on sale.

Registration periods also vary depending on the domain and registrar.

There is no easy answer to your question. You should search the domain you want to register and try on different registrars to see the price options.

Comment: what i mean is that Go-daddy charge as per domain value , one my friend had programming site and traffic was also good , but after one year go-daddy ask 1152$ to renew his domain , which is not normal price value , normal price value to - renew a domain was 12$ at that time , so my question is , is there any site which do not make partiality to renew domain name , whether my site have high traffic or not ?

Comment: What happend to your friend without further detail makes no sense. Maybe he was using a special top-level domain and had an extra expensive price, but the only reason godaddy would charge that much is if he forgot to renew it and did it afterwards.